# Closed Timelike Curves and relatively stationary wormholes

Tags: faster-than-light, wormholes, closed-timelike-curve

Apologies in advance if this question is off topic, I wasn't sure if this was the most appropriate SE forum or not.

Wormholes are one of the most often cited examples of a possibility for faster than light travel.  Like other FTL systems, wormholes are said to provide a mechanism to violate causality if they provide faster than light travel or communications.  The example usually given in these cases is to relativisticaly accelerate one end of the wormhole after it's been created, to subject it to time dilation, and cause the two ends of the wormhole to exist in close spatial proximity but different time periods.

I'm curious if this problem still exists, or if there are other causality violating / CTC creating issues with wormholes if the ends are not accelerated relative to one another after they are created.  Nothing pops immediately to mind, but I am not a physicist, just a layperson with a hobbyists understanding.

Comment: As far as I know the theory states that one would have to travel faster than light to traverse a wormhole. Two objects can meet in the middle but never cross.

Comment: @Wookie - That is just for Einstein-Rosen bridges (they pinch off fast). Morris-Thorne wormholes are traversable.

Comment: another standard method of inducing a time shift is just to have the two wormholes in a different gravitational potential